# Sticky footer weird IE11 behavior

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This fiddle is trying to replicate issue I encountered recently. Therefore, I apologize for messy code since it is a rip of a larger project.

```
fiddle:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kfh3ah4q/4/

**The issue is that this code behaves differently in IE11 than in other Firefox/Chrome.**

The purple part represents sticky footer which is revealed when you scroll to the bottom of the page. In IE, this purple block isnt behaving correctly or it is not even visible at all.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your clearFix class is messing with it. But, I'm not going to hazard an edit because I'm not sure what results you're hoping for out of that class.

Comment: I thought .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; } is correct way to clearfix. I am hoping to find out why IE behaves differently than other browser in this case.

Comment: But you are right, I tested it. Is there any way around? I need the clearfix class as it is now.

Comment: , because __________. (?) If you're simply putting it in lots of places because it "seems to fix random issues" then you may want to research the cause of those issues. I don't see any floats in your CSS, so I don't think you need it as much as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <body style="overflow:scroll;">  

<div class="main clearfix">



  <div class="content contentclosed clearfix">
    <div class="maincontent clearfix" style="position:absolute;">


      <div id="main">

        <section id="znalosti">

                sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text

       </section><!-- end #znalosti -->
      </div><!-- end #main -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer clearfix" style="position:relative;">
        <div class="container">
            <br>&nbsp;</br>
            <p>
            sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text<br>sample text
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>       
  </div>

</div>


</body>
```

I added the overflow scroll to body, position:absolute to the maincontent. Wrapped your footer content in a p and added a line break at the top, and position relative to the footer. You can see my changes inline in the HTML. That worked but all of those things might not be necessary. I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish but I hope that helps.

it worked when i added "overflow:scroll; min-height:2000px;" to your  in IE

Comment: I added your code to fiddle but it doesnt work in IE and even other browsers :(

Comment: are you sure that you did it right? I just pasted this over your HTML and it works for me.

Comment: Look at the text in purple div when you scrolling it. Mine stays in the place, your is moving.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. You want some of the text in the footer to stay hidden. I thought you didnt want it to be positioned behind the div like that. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want it to do? I would like to understand 100% before messing with the fiddle again.

Comment: I just want the IE behave like chrome or firefox now.

Comment: it worked when i added "overflow:scroll; min-height:2000px;" to your <body> in IE. So dont use any of the other code I gave you. It was not clear what you wanted. Just use the code in your fiddle and add the stuff I am mentioning now.

Comment: That unfortunately adds horizontal scrollbar in ie + the footer is much longer than before because of min height

Comment: you can adjust the min height to your liking. you can add "overflow-x:hidden;" that will prevent the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94731/discussion-between-isaac-shiffman-and-user1590642).